# Most secure way of connecting an intranet to an external server

Tags: windows, .net, wcf, security, networking

I have an internal server that hosts an asp.net intranet application. I want to keep it completely and utterly secure and private however we need to expose some information through a WCF service to another server which hosts our external websites which CAN be accessed by the public. What is the best way to pass information between the two servers with regards to an IT setup, while keeping the intranet in house server completely secure and inaccessible? I've heard VPN was the way to go but I wanted to be sure this was the safest way.

Another question what would be the most secure way of passing data in the WCF service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all start deploying your webserver that needs to be accessed from the internet in a so-called Demilitarized Zone (DMZ):

[image]

This will make sure your internet users will NEVER reach the Internal network directly, because the inner firewall is not allowing connections from your external ip through.

Then, host your WCF service in the internal network, and allow only the ip address of the web server to communicate with your WCF endpoint.You can elevate security by securing the line with certificates and client-authentication.

This is a defacto standard used by a lot of companies. Specific further additions or enhancements are possible, but this picture shows the general concept.

Comment: Thanks this is what I'm looking for do you know where I can read up on this in more detail?

Comment: http://www.skullbox.net/configureDMZnetwork.php
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)
http://www.spamlaws.com/how-dmz-works.html